# when i try to acces the gedit as root user it shows the error like this

Tags: gedit, fedora-17

when i try to acces the gedit as root user it shows the error like this:

```
root@localhost Downloads# gedit
No protocol specified
Cannot open display: 
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

Comment: Are you logged in as 'root' at the time or are you logged in as another user (and that other, non-root, user have rights to write to the X display) ?

Comment: Give us some more info. Is your X working?Have you tried restarting :)? have you tried using some non graphic editors like nano,pico,vi,vim...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the display manually to run GUI applications in a session with different environments. To figure out which display is in use try `ps a -o args | grep /[X]` and see if you find an argument like `:number` (commonly `:0`). You should be able to run the application with that value, like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gedit
```